# Recursion Issue

Tags: java, recursion

So I am attempting to have a simple recursion method that prints the digits of a number backwards. I hard-coded the length-1 of the digit in, so if I had a four digit number, length would be three. But for some reason it's only returning the last digit of my number.

```
static int len=3;
public static int backwards(int copy)
{
    if(copy==0)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return backwards(copy/10) + (int)Math.pow(10, len--)*copy%10;

}
```

Comment: For the love of Jon Skeet, please don't use global variables... also, see [Operator Precedence](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should make call to backwards() in recursive function after

```
(int)Math.pow(10, len--)*copy%10;
```

since you have set you len varibale as static so it will decreases after each recursive call, so in the first call you will only get len = 0 and also you should put copy%10 in parenthesis for this to work due to precedence order.

Below code will do your work.

```
 static int len=3;
  public static int backwards(int copy)
  {
    if(copy==0)
    {
      return 0;
    }
    return  (int)Math.pow(10, len--)*(copy%10) + backwards(copy/10);
  }
```

Comment: This will still only work once, and only for a 4-digit number. You have not addressed the bad practice of using that global variable.

Comment: i just helped for the code part that have some bug/issue, though i agree it is bad practice to use global variable and also hardcoding that "len" variable, but its upto the user, how he want to do that or deal with that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What about this simple logic? Printing the remainder `(number %10 )`from the last that gives the reverse of the number.
We can get the last digit of a number by taking the `modulus`(number % 10). Print the last digit `recursively` and you will get the desired result.

```
public static void backwards(int copy)
{
    if(copy<=0)
       return;
    System.out.print(copy%10);
    backwards(copy/10);
}
```